# Trying to install MATE desktop enviroment, getting "Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages"

Tags: apt

So like the title says, Im trying to install the MATE desktop enviroment with the terminal, and I'm using the wiki instructions at http://wiki.mate-desktop.org/download - but everytime I enter "sudo apt-get install mate-core", I get stuck with this..

```
username@computer:~$ sudo apt-get install mate-core
Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done Some packages could not be installed. This
may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are
using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not
yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. The following
information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:  mate-core : Depends:
mate-control-center (>= 1.6.0) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: caja (>= 1.6.0) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: marco (>= 1.6.0) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: mate-session-manager (>= 1.6.0) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: mate-panel (>= 1.6.0) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: mate-settings-daemon (>= 1.6.0) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: mate-terminal (>= 1.6.0) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: mate-desktop (>= 1.6.0) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: libmatekbd (>= 1.6.0) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: libmatedesktop (>= 1.6.0) but it is not going to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I'm not really sure what this means since im a complete noob with Ubuntu..can anybody help?

Answer (score -1):

This means that the other software required to install mate-core is not available on the servers. Try running theses commands: sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://packages.mate-desktop.org/repo/ubuntu precise main" && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get install mate-core